# Applying geometric calculus to a matrix expression

Tags: multivariable-calculus, geometric-algebras

Let $f(\mathbf x) = \mathbf x^T A \mathbf x + \mathbf b^T\mathbf x + c$, where $A$ is a square matrix, $\mathbf x, \mathbf b$ are column matrices and $c$ is a constant.  Then the gradient of this expression is $\nabla f(\mathbf x) = (A+A^T)\mathbf x + \mathbf b$.  I see how to derive this by interpretting the gradient as the matrix operator $D$.  I'm wondering if we could get the same answer if we used the geometric gradient defined by $\nabla = \sum_i \mathbf e^i \partial_i$.  So I'd like to know how to use [geometric calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_calculus) on this matrix expression.  Is there a way to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it:
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x}) &= \sum_{ij} x_{i}a_{ij}x_{j} + \sum_{i} b_{i}x_{i} + c \\
&= \sum_{i} a_{ii}x_{i}^2 + b_{i}x_{i} + \sum_{i\ne j} x_{i}a_{ij}x_{j} + c
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
\nabla f(\mathbf{x}) 
&=
\sum_{k} \mathbf{e}^{k}\partial_{k}\left(  \sum_{i} a_{ii}x_{i}^2 + b_{i}x_{i} + \sum_{i\ne j} x_{i}a_{ij}x_{j}\right) \\
&=
\sum_{k} \mathbf{e}^{k}\left(2a_{kk}x_{k} + \sum_{j}a_{kj}x_{j} + \sum_{i}a_{ik}x_{i} + b_{k} \right) \\
&=
\sum_{k} \mathbf{e}^{k}\left(((A+A^T)\mathbf{x})_{k} + b_{k} \right) \\
&=
(A+A^T)\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{b}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

First, let's go away from explicitly talking about things as matrices and column/row vectors.  What you have is basically

$$f(x) = x \cdot A(x) + b \cdot x + c$$

We can use a simple identity here:  for any constant vector $a$, and $\nabla = \nabla_x$, we have

$$\nabla (a \cdot x) = a$$

Expanding the $x \cdot A(x)$ term by the product rule allows us to apply this identity:

$$\begin{align*}\nabla f &= \nabla (x \cdot A[x]) + \nabla (b \cdot x) + \nabla c 
\\ &= \dot \nabla (\dot x \cdot A[x]) + \dot \nabla (x \cdot A[\dot x]) + b + 0  \end{align*}$$

Here, we've used overdots to denote what is differentiated: $\dot \nabla$ differentiates only $\dot x$.  This gives us some of the flexibility of index notation without actually breaking into components.

Now, use the relation $u \cdot M(v) = M^T(u) \cdot v$ for any linear operator $M$ and vectors $u,v$.  This allows us to cast the $\dot \nabla(x \cdot A[\dot x])$ term into the more tractable $\dot \nabla (A^T[x] \cdot \dot x)$ instead, on which we can use the gradient identity established earlier.  The result is then

$$\begin{align*}\nabla f &= \dot \nabla (\dot x \cdot A[x]) + \dot \nabla (A^T[x] \cdot \dot x) + b \\ &= A(x) + A^T(x) + b \\
&= (A + A^T)(x) + b\end{align*}$$

The keys to avoiding index notation are the gradient identity $\nabla (x \cdot a) = a$ and the overdot notation for dealing with the product rule terms.  The transpose identity is also crucial.

Comment: Why is it $\dot \nabla (x \cdot A[\dot x])$ instead of $\dot \nabla (x \cdot \dot {[A[x]]})$?

Comment: @gotit--thanks I wrote it that way to make it more clear what would happen once we use the transpose. Since $A$ is a linear map, it makes no difference in this case.